# how to get child table along with the parent in entity framework using entity sql like "select value tablename from tablename"

Tags: entity-framework, entity

how to get child table along with the parent in entity framework using entity sql query 
for example
var parentTable = "select value parentTable from parentTable as pt inner join childTable as ct on pt.key = ct.key";

doing this parentTable.childTable.count() returns 0.

so how can i get the childTable loaded along with the parent table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You call Include() on your ObjectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx), just like you do with LINQ to Entities. It's no different if you create your query using ESQL.